# Regular expression for RFC822 standard

Tags: php, regex, email

We are facing issue that can be fixed with regular expression: https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser/issues/176
Some email addresses are not compilant to RFC822 standard. 
There is problem with special chars (ex. `>`, `@`) that are not within quotes `"` and are not an email address.

Here is as input variants:

- `Neuman@BBN-TENEXA`
- `Alfred > Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`
- `Alfred > Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, Alfred Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, "Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, Alfred > Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`
- `"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`
- `Alfred @ Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`

And this is needed output:

- `Neuman@BBN-TENEXA`
- `"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`
- `"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, Alfred Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, "Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, "Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`
- `"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`
- `"Alfred @ Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>`

Can anyone help to create such replace reg exp?

Comment: Your input example includes thing that are not email addresses. if you have special chars which are not (part of) an email address then why are they part of your problem? You don't have a clear problem statement.The reason email addresses have the structure they do is they can be parsed - if data is written in a non-parseable format, it cannot be parsed. While you'd get more mileage out of FSM than a regex, there are too many edge cases for your imp[lementation ever to be provably correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: `".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+\s[<>@]\s\w+)` **Substitution**: `"$1"`

Or if you want to be more precise use:

`"\w+\s[<>@]\s\w+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+\s[<>@]\s\w+)`

`"Alfred\s[<>@]\sNeuman"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(Alfred\s[<>@]\sNeuman)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VaA2mm/1)

**PHP code**:

```
$text = 'Neuman@BBN-TENEXA
Alfred > Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
Alfred > Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, Alfred Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, "Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, Alfred > Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
Alfred @ Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>';

$text = preg_replace("/\".*?\"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+\s[<>@]\s\w+)/", "\"$1\"", $text);
print_r($text);
```

**Output**:

```
Neuman@BBN-TENEXA
"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, Alfred Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, "Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>, "Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
"Alfred > Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
"Alfred @ Neuman" <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
```